# replace substring between two substrings on every match

Tags: javascript

Is there a faster built-in function in JavaScript to replace a substring2 between two substrings with a sequence of numbers the length of substring2, than looping the whole string and replace it by hand.

example:

substring before: `"before"`

substring after: `"after"`

if `substring2 is length of 3` => replace with `string 011`

if `substring2 is length of 6` => replace with `string 999999`
string:

`"beforeoooafter beforeaftebefore123456afteradf"`

ooo would be the substring2 and 123456 too

ooo => 011 (because length 3)

123456 => 999999 (because length 6)

substring2 is a match between the string before and after

result:

`"before011after beforeaftebefore999999afteradf"`

Comment: If you'd like people to help you improve your code, please share it.

Comment: Add youre code, the question is not clear enough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You replace 3 characters and one set of digits. It is very hard to guess the rules here

Comment: `before` is also the length of 6

Comment: Not sure why I get the digits in separate matches `str.match(/(.)\1{2}|\d\1{6}/g)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression and a replace function:

```js
const input = "beforeoooafter beforeaftebefore123456afteradf";

const expectedOutput = "before011after beforeaftebefore999999afteradf";

const output = input.replace(/(before(?:(?!before|after).)*after)/g, function(m) {
  const before = 'before';
  const after = 'after';
  const middle = m.substr(before.length, m.length - after.length - before.length);
  if (middle.length === 3) {
    return before + '011' + after;
  } else if (middle.length === 6) {
    return before + '999999' + after;
  }
  return m;
});

console.log(output);
console.log(output === expectedOutput);
```

Comment: thanks works perfectly fine and faster than the looping solution!